# Recorrer todas las opciones de un combobox para Web Scrapping

Tags: c#, web, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

Buen día, estoy aprendiendo el Web Scrapping y Web crawling para desarrollo de automatizaciones desde código de programación.

mi consulta es la siguiente: ¿Comó puedo obtener todos los valores de un combobox de un portal?
voy a crear un ciclo for para que se recorrán todos esos valores en mi webcrawler, pero necesito saber como guardar esos values para poder ciclarlos.

c# código

```
//go to site to scratch
               driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/scpei001/controlador?Destino=scpei001_01.jsp");
               //obtain all optionvaluescombobox
               var combobox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("icto"));
               //create select element object 
               var optioncomboxinteres = new SelectElement(combobox);
               optioncomboxinteres.SelectByValue("613");
               string combotabla = "//form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input";
               var createtabla = driver.FindElementByXPath(combotabla);
               createtabla.Click();
```

en el código,ya seleccione un value de todos los disponibles del combobox, pero quiero obtener todos los values y guardarlos, para declarar esa variable y pueda ir seleccionando cada value.

código HTML del portal

```
<select name="icto" onchange="submit();">                       


                               <option selected="" value="0">-- Seleccione un Centro --</option>




                                           <option value="613">613-TAD GOMEZ PALACIO, DGO.</option>



                                           <option value="617">617-TAD AGUASCALIENTES, AGS.</option>



                                           <option value="624">624-TAD ZACATECAS, ZAC.</option>



                                           <option value="627">627-TAD EL CASTILLO, JAL.</option>



                                           <option value="628">628-TAD TEPEIXTLES, COL.</option>



                                           <option value="630">630-TAD ZAPOPAN, JAL.</option>



                                           <option value="631">631-TAD LAZARO CARDENAS, MICH.</option>



                                           <option value="636">636-TAD ROSARITO, B.C.N.</option>



                                           <option value="638">638-TAD MEXICALI, B.C.N.</option>



                                           <option value="640">640-TAD MAGDALENA, SON.</option>



                                           <option value="645">645-TAD TOPOLOBAMPO, SIN.</option>



                                           <option value="647">647-TAD CULIACAN, SIN.</option>



                                           <option value="648">648-TAD GUAMUCHIL, SIN.</option>



                                           <option value="654">654-TAD LEON, GTO.</option>



                                           <option value="655">655-TAD MORELIA, MICH.</option>



                                           <option value="656">656-TAD QUERETARO, QRO.</option>



                                           <option value="657">657-TAD TOLUCA, MEX.</option>



                                           <option value="658">658-TAD CELAYA, GTO.</option>



                                           <option value="660">660-TAD ZAMORA, MICH.</option>



                                           <option value="661">661-TAD IRAPUATO, GTO.</option>



                                           <option value="663">663-TAD PUEBLA, PUE.</option>



                                           <option value="667">667-TAD PACHUCA, HGO.</option>



                                           <option value="673">673-TAD VERACRUZ, VER.</option>



                                           <option value="674">674-TAD ESCAMELA, VER.</option>



                                           <option value="678">678-TAD POZA RICA, VER.</option>



                                           <option value="693">693-TAD TULA, HGO.</option>



                                           <option value="695">695-TAD SAN JUAN IXHUATEPEC, MEX.</option>



                                           <option value="696">696-TAD ANIL, D.F.</option>



                                           <option value="697">697-TAD BARRANCA DEL MUERTO, D.F.</option>



                                           <option value="699">699-TAD 18 DE MARZO, AZC.,DF</option>



                                           <option value="701">701-SAN JOSE ITURBIDE</option>



                                           <option value="704">704-TADT LAGOS DE MORENO</option>






                       </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podria ver de usar `Options`

```
var combobox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("icto"));
IList<IWebElement> ictoOptions= combobox.Options;

foreach (IWebElement option in ictoOptions)
{

}
```

Pero tambien podrias seleccionar las opciones

```
var combobox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("icto"));
List<WebElement> ictoOptions = combobox.FindElements(By.tagName("option"));
```

Fuentes:

[How to get all options in a drop-down list by Selenium WebDriver using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562853/how-to-get-all-options-in-a-drop-down-list-by-selenium-webdriver-using-c)

[C# Selenium: How to count elements and get selected option from a selection element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538333/c-sharp-selenium-how-to-count-elements-and-get-selected-option-from-a-selection)